# Listen to any new document added to a collection in firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The existing solutions are not working for me, I've tried. What I'm trying to do is to fetch messages in a thread that is stored on Firestore. This is the current structure of Chat collection:

[image]

As you can see this chat between user 1 and user 2 only has 2 messages and I'm trying to fetch these and also listen to new ones if they are added to thread. Here is the code of how I'm doing it:

```
func loadChat() {

    self.showWaitOverlayWithText("Loading")
    let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("Chats")
        .whereField("user1ID", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "Not Found User 1")
        .whereField("user2UID", isEqualTo: user2UID ?? "Not Found User 2")

    db.getDocuments { (querySnap, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return
        } else {
            let doc = querySnap?.documents.first

           doc?.reference.collection("thread").addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true, listener: { (threadQuery, error) in
                //Never comes here
                for message in threadQuery!.documents {
                    self.removeAllOverlays()
                    print("Data: \(message.data())")
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

It never executes `collection("thread").addSnapshotListner`.

Comment: Is it printing an error? That is, it is entering the first scenario of the conditional statement (`if let error = error {`)

Comment: no it never execute the `addSnapShotListner` part

Comment: I understand that, but is it printing an error in the completion handler for `getDocuments  { }`? Or is it calling `doc?.reference.collection("thread").addsnapshotListener` but that completion handler is never executing?

Comment: Try changing `doc?.reference.collection("thread").addSnapshotListener(` to `doc!.reference.collection("thread").addSnapshotListener(` and see if the app crashes. What may be happening is that line simply isn't executing because `doc` is `nil`.

Comment: So it is executing `getDocuments` and there is no error in it. Then in `addSnapshotListner` it never executes even if I add `if let error = error` under `addSnapshotListner`

Comment: doing `doc!` gives me `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: See my above suggestion. We need to make sure that `doc` isn't equal to `nil`, or else it won't execute. Maybe set a breakpoint immediately after `let doc = querySnap?.documents.first` and check if `doc` is equal to `nil`.

Comment: Don't bother with getDocuments.  Just use a listener to both get the current documents and also receive new documents.

Comment: Okay, so the issue is that `let doc = querySnap?.documents.first` is returning `nil`. Or, similarly, `querySnap` is equal to `nil`.

Comment: yes you are right it's `nil. Fixing it now.

Comment: Is it `querySnap` or `doc` that is `nil`? I imagine it is likely both.

Comment: I printed `doc` and `querySnap?.document.count` and the output was `nil` and `0` and I'm still not sure why it's not fetching the document. I've check and the `whereField` is accurate as it's printing both user's id correct.

Comment: found a stupid mistake the key name is `User2ID` not `User2UID`

Comment: If that is the case, then the issue lies in this line `let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("Chats").whereField("user1ID", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "Not Found User 1").whereField("user2UID", isEqualTo: user2UID ?? "Not Found User 2`. Can you check what `Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` and `user2UID` to make sure neither one is `nil` and that they are strings that match up with your database?

Comment: The issue is fixed now. It was because of the wrong key.

Comment: Awesome, do you mind if I post an answer that outlines how we pinpointed this?

Comment: @DavidChopin sure please do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue was simply an incorrect key in the query, "user2UID" instead of "user2ID". We were able to pinpoint this issue by checking whether or not the optional values (`doc`, `querySnap`) were nil or not. `doc` was equal to nil, `querySnap` was not, but its document count was equal to zero. This helped us know that the issue was with the line

```swift
let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("Chats")
       .whereField("user1ID", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "Not Found User 1")
       .whereField("user2UID", isEqualTo: user2UID ?? "Not Found User 2")
```

I initially thought the issue would have been an inconsistency with the values, not the keys, on the backend. A second look by Chaundhry confirmed that there was an incorrect key.